# div border - Collapsing to 0 height

Tags: html, css, border

Please check out this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dNJxd/1/

As you can see in there, the divs at `.left_field > div` and `.right_field > div` have a border on them.  However, that border is "collapsing" to 0 height.

If I change the `overflow` to `hidden` (all the similar questions are advocating for that), it fixes the issue, but that's not an option because it cuts off the date control that I'm using.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the spelling fix, ManseUK.

Comment: :-) thought i should change it !!!!

Answer (score 2):

In the following segment:

```
<div>
    <span class="field_label">PO Number:</span>
    <span class="field_data">12345</span>
</div>
```

The first span has `position: absolute;` and as such assumes no space in its container, and the second is floating, which has that same effect on container space, unless it is cleared.

The following code will not have the same issue:

```
<div>
    <span class="field_label">PO Number:</span>
    <span class="field_data">12345</span>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6fGR/)

Comment: Thanks so much!  After some extra googling, I came across [this post](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/), which resulted in me adding [this CSS](http://pastie.org/3910156).