# Clearing elements with div:after

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

While looking for a solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10584744/196838), I attempted to add a clearing element with the `:after` pseudo-class. It did what I want, but not for the reason I expected - after narrowing things down I found out that defining the following clears the elements:

```
.right_field > div:after
{
    content: "style=\"foo\"";
}
```

What I would expect it to do is append the text `style="foo"` to the end of the `div` elements inside the `.right_field`, but instead it adds nothing visual and clears the elements so that they wrap around their floating children.

See the following fiddle for a demonstration. Try removing the `foo` from inside the content property and see how it no longer clears the element and instead just appends the text to each of them.
 http://jsfiddle.net/dNJxd/5/

Why does this happen, and is this a feature that can be counted on? I tested it on Chrome, Firefox and IE7-9 and they all worked the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example does append the text `style="foo"` after the `div` element. The only browser that wouldn't do this (from your list of tested browsers) is IE7 because it does not support the `::after` pseudo class.

Maybe you need to stretch out your [JSFiddle result window](http://jsfiddle.net/dNJxd/5/embedded/result/) a little further.

Also, this does not clear the float - it just gives the parent div some height since the appended text is not floated. The border collapse will still occur when the content of the `div` has a larger height than the appended text.

Comment: You're right, my browser window was just too narrow. The text wrapped and was obscured by the grey area, tricking me to thinking the div had been cleared. Thanks!

Comment: No problem - looks can be deceiving sometimes ;)